# How to Enable deprecate methods warning in gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

When I build a project with gradle I'm unable to see any warning about deprecated methods, only the errors are shown.

How do I have to set build.gradle to show also all deprecations warning(without prevent the build completion)?

Answer (score 9):

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

you can put in in your top-level build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```

or in your module one :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. (Seems related only to java xlint warnings)

Comment: When I run the gradle task `gradle app:build` I can clearly see :  warning: [deprecation] ***() in *** has been deprecated

Comment: could you post the full build.gradle file that you use?

Comment: You can only see the warning at the compilation, be sure to clean you project (Build -> Clean Project).

to see Gradle output, you need to open "Gradle Console" window (bottom right tab)

Comment: Still I cannot see any warning about deprecated android class and methods. The Gradle console has a tons of logs but I don't see anything about deprecated. Is there some specific section that I have to open?

Comment: For me the "Gradle Console" shows only one line per executed task, the warning appear in red. Do you have any gradle plugins with APT or similar ?

Comment: the deprecation warning also appears in the "Messages" window

Comment: the problem is that in message windows I don't see any deprecation. The same project created in non-gradle way shows deprecation... so something with gradle isn't configured correctly

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, warning is shown in my Messages with the build.gradle file I posted. Did you refresh the Gradle config (refresh button in the right Gradle panel)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.warning.mode=all
```

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties